# How to achieve this particular screen filter with GLSL?

Tags: 2d, shaders, glsl

I know this may be a "short" question, but still here it goes.

I would like to know how to achieve a post rendering effect, that looks like the following image from walking dead series:

[image]

I will make the art already fitting the style, but what if I want to make the colors more coherent by adding a color filter such as the one in the picture?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, it looks to me like a lot of the blue has been removed from that image.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9402041/160539

Comment: That looks like sepia or exaggerated technicolor: there are a bunch of glsl shaders out there that do this (http://www.moddb.com/mods/fxaa-post-process-injector for example).

Answer (score 3):

What you could do to match this scene:

- **Grunge**. Multiply dirt textures into the meshes' textures to make it look rustic.
- **Fog and clouds**. If you notice, the brown clouds and dusty fog really pull this scene together.
- **Sepia**. As Johnathan Dickinson mentioned, you could use a sepia shader to finish it off.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest approach to sepia would be to mix every resulting pixel with sepia color at specified proportion. Pseudocode: `Result.rgb = lerp(Color.rgb, Sepia.rgb, Factor);` Where Sepia tone may need some tweaking as well (check these variants for example: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepia_(color)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepia_%28color%29))